# Filter by multiple values

Tags: google-sheets

To explain what I want to do, I will show a much simpler version of my spreadsheet:
[image: Filter]

I want to be able to filter the `Tags to filter` column using multiple value of the column `Filters available`.

For instance, if I select the filters available `e` and `d`, I will get back only the lines 15,15 and 17.

My problem is that I don't know how to select the filters that I want and filter the table.

The perfect solution would be to have a list with checkboxes like the one shown in the following picture:
[image: Filter2]

But instead of showing the exact values in this column, it should show the ones in the `Filters available` table, and after it would filter to show the lines that contains at least one of the options selected...

Do you think I made my question clear?

Answer (score 1):

Try using one extra column with filter condition:

[image]

In this sample:

1. Range A2:A8 = filters available
2. Range B2:B8 = range where user selects, which filter to use, pasting ones.
3. Range D2:D9 = tags to filter
4. Range E2:E9 = extra column with condition

You need only one formula in cell E2:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(D2:D9,JOIN("|",FILTER(A2:A8,B2:B8=1))))
```

---

`ArrayFormula` will make it expand down to row 9 automatically. Select your range instead of D2:D9.

`REGEXMATCH` checks if tags contains selected filters.

`JOIN` makes string like this: "a|c|e|g" which makes `REGEXMATCH` to check for any of selected filters: a OR c OR e OR g.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way of doing this it to use a Pivot Table.

Highlight the data you want to use, then select Pivot Table from the Data menu.

Then Add field to select the Rows and Columns you are after, and include the column you want to filter by in the Filter field

Then you can use the built in Pivot Table Filter to show what you are after.

[Giant image showing how to setup and use a pivot table in google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNmIf.png)

here is a link to the google help for how to create a pivot table:

[Link to google help tutorial for how to use pivot tables](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900)

Comment: I'm not understanding your solution... Can you add some more details? Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, I've added an example image of how to use a pivot table, and some sample tables and how they would be filtered, I've also added a link to the tutorial for how to use google sheets and pivot tables.

Comment: @amp did that help? if not can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Sadly not, because in your example, in the filter column, you only have one value... In my case, I have multiple possible values separated by commas. So this doesn't work for me...

Comment: @amp Can you provide a better example of your sample then if Max's doesn't work, so we can try to get you an answer.