# Filter a data in excel or google sheets using tags

Tags: excel, sorting, filtering, tagging

I think a similar question has been asked once here ([Filter by multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403007/filter-by-multiple-values)) , but the scenario I'm looking for is slightly different.

I would like to filter my data using the values in a row. But a single row can have multiple values of the "filter data".

I think tagging the rows(like in blog post) might be helpful to sort the data. But I couldn't find a way of tagging rows.

Like mentioned in the above example, tags are "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"
and a single row can have multiple tags like "c,f".

Is there any way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you could use conditional formatting. You can create a rule that will highlight a cell if it contains certain text

e.g.
if you have rows

- a
- b
- c
- a, c
- d
- g, a

and create a rule that highlights text containing a then the (a),(a, c) and (g, a) rows will be highlighted

Comment: That would just highlight the cells with the required text. But I'd like to filter the data with the required text.